# iText signature verification issue

Tags: java, itext, digital-signature, verification

I'm following the iText 5 signature verification example to build a sign/verify pdf with digital signature. However it return error when i compile the java as below error message:

```
Signatures.java:221: error: incompatible types: List<VerificationException> cannot be converted to Object[]
  Object fails[] = CertificateVerification.verifyCertificates(pkc, ks, null, cal);
1 error
```

here my java code:

```
public void verifySignatures() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        ks.load(null, null);
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
        FileInputStream is1 = new FileInputStream(properties.getProperty("ROOTCERT"));
        X509Certificate cert1 = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(is1);
        ks.setCertificateEntry("cacert", cert1);
        FileInputStream is2 = new FileInputStream("12345678.cer");
        X509Certificate cert2 = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(is2);
        ks.setCertificateEntry("foobar", cert2);
        
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(VERIFICATION));
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SIGNED1);
        AcroFields af = reader.getAcroFields();
        ArrayList<String> names = af.getSignatureNames();
        for (String name : names) {
            out.println("Signature name: " + name);
            out.println("Signature covers whole document: "+ af.signatureCoversWholeDocument(name));
            out.println("Document revision: "+ af.getRevision(name)+" of "+ af.getTotalRevisions());
            PdfPKCS7 pk = af.verifySignature(name);
            Calendar cal = pk.getSignDate();
            Certificate[] pkc = pk.getCertificates();
            out.println("Subject: " + CertificateInfo.getSubjectFields(pk.getSigningCertificate()));
            out.println("Revision modified: " + !pk.verify());
            Object fails[] = CertificateVerification.verifyCertificates(pkc, ks, null, cal);
            
            if (fails == null)
                out.println("Certificates verified against the KeyStore");
            else
                out.println("Certificate failed: " + fails[1]);    
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
```

what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> Signatures.java:221: error: incompatible types:
> List cannot be converted to Object[]   Object
> fails[] = CertificateVerification.verifyCertificates(pkc, ks, null,
> cal); 1 error

You're invoking the following method of iText5 class `CertificateVerification`

```
public static List<VerificationException> verifyCertificates(Certificate[] certs, KeyStore keystore,
        Calendar calendar) {
    return verifyCertificates(certs, keystore, (Collection) null, calendar);
}
```

Change `Object fails[]` to `List<VerificationException>`.